# Bootstrap Panel is not working for some color

Tags: html, css, panel

I am using Bootstrap Panel. Here is my css:

```
.panel-green {
   border-color: #649f2b;
}
.panel-green > .panel-heading {
   background-color: #4b7720;
   border-color: #7dc736;
   color: #FFFFFF;
}
.panel-green .panel-footer {
   background: #649f2b;
   border-color: #7dc736;
   color: #FFFFFF;
}
.panel-green [class^="fa-"]:before,
.panel-green [class*=" fa-"]:before {
   color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
   margin-right: 5px;
}
.panel-yellow {
   border-color: #d0b426;
}
.panel-yellow > .panel-heading {
   background-color: #a58f1e;
   border-color: #dec64b;
   color: #FFFFFF;
}
.panel-yellow .panel-footer {
   background: #d0b426;
   border-color: #dec64b;
   color: #FFFFFF;
}
.panel-yellow [class^="fa-"]:before,
.panel-yellow [class*=" fa-"]:before {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    margin-right: 5px;
 }
```

and here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="panel panel-green">
   <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">A Heading</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="panel-body">
      <p>some content </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

It works fine for panel-green, but when i put panel-yellow in the HTML instead of panel-green, it doesn't work anymore.It shows only a box without any color,no heading or body separator. What is the problem? What am i missing?

Comment: add your code like jsfiddle

Answer (score -1):

Check this, you have to change the class "panel-yellow" in your html also.

```css
    .panel-green {
    border-color: #649f2b;
}
.panel-green > .panel-heading {
background-color: #4b7720;
border-color: #7dc736;
color: #FFFFFF;
}
.panel-green .panel-footer {
background: #649f2b;
border-color: #7dc736;
color: #FFFFFF;
 }
.panel-green [class^="fa-"]:before,
.panel-green [class*=" fa-"]:before {
color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
margin-right: 5px;
}
.panel-yellow {
border-color: #d0b426;
}
.panel-yellow > .panel-heading {
background-color: #a58f1e;
border-color: #dec64b;
color: #FFFFFF;
}
.panel-yellow .panel-footer {
background: #d0b426;
border-color: #dec64b;
color: #FFFFFF;
}
.panel-yellow [class^="fa-"]:before,
.panel-yellow [class*=" fa-"]:before {
 color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
 margin-right: 5px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="panel panel-yellow">
  <div class="panel-heading">
  <h3 class="panel-title">A Heading</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
  <p>some content </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand.That was my question!!!! It should work when i change the class into panel-yellow in HTML, But it doesn't. That is the problem.

Comment: Did you see the snippet, Its working. Panel is Yellow.

Comment: yeah i saw the snippet. But the same code didn't work in my case. But thanx anyway. Maybe it's some css which conflict with this.